# Как создать веб документ формата A4-A9 для печати?

Tags: php, html, css

Что нужно получить?
На веб странице есть блок DIV, например, черный прямоуголник. При распечатке нужно, чтобы этот блок был размера A9 (+- 1 мм). Напомню, размер А9 37*52 миллиметра.

Что было сделано?
Пробовал задавать размеры в пикселях. Пробовал эту таблицу конвертации:
[Конвертер](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/RU/units-converter/typography/7-4/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(X)-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80/)
В нашем случае должно быть в пикселях примерно width=140, height=196.

Пробовал вместо пикселей использовать мм. Например:

```
.div.A9 {
    width: 37mm;
    height: 52mm;
}
```

В обоих случая при распечатке разница громадная +-10-15 мм

Есть ли какие то способы правильно получить размеры для печати?
Тестировал в Хроме последней версии.

UPD: Может конвертировать данные в PDF(нужна точность размеров)? Какие у вас варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил не заморачиваться ПДФ версией. 
Вот несколько советов, которые помогут вам распечатать документ заданного размера.

1. Жестко задайте ориентацию документа. Книжный, альбомный . Это уменшить поток вопросов "Ой он у меня распечатался как книга. Как распечатать альбомно....?"

   @page {
   size: portait, landscape
   }
2. Уберите поля при печати. Иначе у вас не вместятся два А5 на одном листе.

   @page {
       margin: 0;
   }
3. Найдите правильное соотношение пиксель - мм. Распечатайте около 15 прямоугольников разных размеров. Измерьте линейкой.
   У меня соотношение составило 3,557142857142857 пикселей на один мм . Скорее всего и у вас так.
4. Обратите внимание как считаются у вас длина блока. то есть box-sizing какой у вас. У меня content. В этом случае к ширине блока добавляются все padding and margin, то есть длина блока может быть больше, чем вы это задали. Учитывайте это.

Это поможет вам сделать документ соответствующий размерам в тютелька в тютельку.

Answer (score 0):

Может так получится

```
<style>
    @media print {
        .divA9 {
            width: 37mm;
            height: 52mm;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="divA9"></div>
```

Ещё проверить, что нет всяких margin, padding. Не помню как они влияют на интерпретацию width и height, но есть разные модели коробки (box model), которые тоже можно менять если надо. Так же не стоит забывать про поля, колонтитулы и прочие опции в диалоге печати.

Конвертер может не правильно рассчитать. Пиксели на принтере скорей всего имеют другой размер, нежели на экране автора сайта.

А pdf и был задуман, что бы всегда и везде печаталось одинаково и точно. Так что конвертируйте.